# Find "secure file erase" commands on the system

Tags: go

This code finds which "secure file erase" command exists on the system.  It used to simply test for "shred" and pick "rm" as a default.  Now it is a bit more complex since I've ported the code to operating systems with "srm" and "rm -P".  Is this still cleanly written?  How can I improve it?

````
var shredPath, shredFlag string // Memoization cache

// shredCmd determines which command to use to securely erase a file. It returns
// the command to run and what flags to use with it. Determining the answer
// can be slow, therefore the answer is memoized and returned to future callers.
func shredCmd() (string, string) {
    // Use the memoized result.
    if shredPath != "" {
        return shredPath, shredFlag
    }

    var path string
    var err error
    if path, err = exec.LookPath("shred"); err == nil {
        shredPath, shredFlag = path, "-u"
    } else if path, err = exec.LookPath("srm"); err == nil {
        shredPath, shredFlag = path, "-f"
    } else if path, err = exec.LookPath("rm"); err == nil {
        shredPath, shredFlag = path, "-f"
        // Does this command support the "-P" flag?
        tmpfile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "rmtest")
        defer os.Remove(tmpfile.Name()) // clean up
        err = RunBash("rm", "-P", tmpfile.Name())
        if err != nil {
            shredFlag = "-Pf"
        }
    }

    // Single exit, so we don't have to repeat the memoization code.
    return shredPath, shredFlag
}

// RunBash runs a Bash command.
func RunBash(command string, args ...string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("RunBash cmd=%q err=%w", command, err)
    }
    return nil
}
```
````

Comment: I would prefer to have `ShredCmd` or `SystemCmd` interface that had `Path() string ,Flag() string,IsAvailable() bool`

Answer (score 2):

You have no synchronization for these package variables

```
var shredPath, shredFlag string
```

Therefore,

```
fmt.Println(shredPath, shredFlag)
go func() {
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        shredCmd()
    }
}()
for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
    shredCmd()
}
fmt.Println(shredPath, shredFlag)

WARNING: DATA RACE
Found 3 data race(s)
```

`os.Remove()` and commands may fail if the file is open.

If you encounter something unexpected, for example Windows, you do nothing, not even `os.Remove()`.

The `if` statements are ugly. Since `shredCmd()` is effectively a test, use the standard testing package technique, table-driven tests.

You provide no context for usage or testing, for example

```
func ShredFile(filename string) error {
    // ...
}
```

And so on.

---

Here's an attempt to fix some of the issues:

`shred.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

var shredCmds = []struct {
    name, opts string
}{
    {"shred", "-u"},
    {"srm", "-f"},
    {"rm", "-Pf"},
    {"rm", "-f"},
    {"sdelete", "-a"},
}

func shredTemp(path, opts string) error {
    file, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "shredTemp.")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    filename := file.Name()
    defer os.Remove(filename)
    defer file.Close()

    err = file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = RunCmd(path, opts, filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

var shredPath, shredOpts = func() (string, string) {
    for _, cmd := range shredCmds {
        path, err := exec.LookPath(cmd.name)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        err = shredTemp(path, cmd.opts)
        if err == nil {
            return path, cmd.opts
        }
    }
    return "", ""
}()

func ShredFile(filename string) error {
    fi, err := os.Stat(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if !fi.Mode().IsRegular() {
        err := errors.New("filename is not mode regular")
        return err
    }

    if shredPath == "" {
        return os.Remove(filename)
    }

    err = RunCmd(shredPath, shredOpts, filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func RunCmd(command string, args ...string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("RunCmd cmd=%q err=%w", command, err)
    }
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("RunCmd cmd=%q err=%w", command, err)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    file, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "ShredFile.")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    filename := file.Name()
    file.Close()
    defer os.Remove(filename)
    start := time.Now()
    err = ShredFile(filename)
    since := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(filename, since, err)
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I hadn't thought of testing the commands like a data-driven unit test. That not only makes it cleaner, it makes it easier to add new commands. Thanks!  (and thanks for all the other feedback)